# Popup contact info on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, popup

I created a VF page for a custom object with a field that is a lookup>contact. When I mouseover the contact on my VF page, it pops up a window with name and account name. Here is my current display code (its inline edit field):

```
<apex:outputField value="{!CustomObject__c.Contact1__c}" > 
<apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
</apex:outputField>
```

Here is a screenshot

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JYtufLnux9bEJxUHNDWDFYQTA/view?usp=sharing

How could I get contact.title to show there as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

goto to contact page layout -> mini pagelayout (top right corner), add fields, save

[image]